# sudo: conda: command not found

Tags: conda

I installed Conda using its 32 bits `.sh` file from [here](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).

Here are the essential parts of the installation procedure that worked fine:

```
Do you approve the license terms? [yes|no]
[no] >>> yes

Miniconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/begueradj/miniconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/begueradj/miniconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/home/begueradj/miniconda3
installing: python-3.4.2-0 ...
installing: conda-env-2.0.1-py34_0 ...
installing: openssl-1.0.1k-0 ...
installing: pycosat-0.6.1-py34_0 ...
installing: pyyaml-3.11-py34_0 ...
installing: readline-6.2-2 ...
installing: requests-2.5.1-py34_0 ...
installing: sqlite-3.8.4.1-0 ...
installing: system-5.8-1 ...
installing: tk-8.5.15-0 ...
installing: xz-5.0.5-0 ...
installing: yaml-0.1.4-0 ...
installing: zlib-1.2.8-0 ...
installing: conda-3.8.3-py34_0 ...
Python 3.4.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
creating default environment...
installation finished.
Do you wish the installer to prepend the Miniconda3 install location
to PATH in your /home/begueradj/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
[no] >>> yes

Prepending PATH=/home/begueradj/miniconda3/bin to PATH in /home/begueradj/.bashrc
A backup will be made to: /home/begueradj/.bashrc-miniconda3.bak


For this change to become active, you have to open a new terminal.

Thank you for installing Miniconda3!
begueradj@begueradj-HP-Compaq-6510b-KE130ET-ABF:~/Desktop$
```

When I type sudo conda install something, I get this error:

```
sudo: conda: command not found
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, I'm not used to find answers to my question this quickly, but for this one I did:

I had only to remove the `sudo` before the `conda` command.

**Explanation:**

All conda commands must be run without super user privileges.

Hope it can help someone in the future.

Comment: Indeed, this is the right answer. Conda installs in the home directory with user privileges. You should avoid using sudo with conda, as that would write files with non-user permissions, and you would have to use sudo every time thereafter to modify those files.

Comment: If I do this, I get a `CondaIOError: Missing write permissions in: /anaconda`.

Comment: @ThomasAhle You should start a new question, you can link this one and specify what exactly you did and what the result was.

Comment: In my case I installed I installed conda to `opt/anaconda` so I now need to run it with sudo. So I fixed it by adding `export PATH="/opt/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` to my sudo bash

Comment: This false. Root permissions are required to edit the `base` environment when a system-wide install is done.

Answer (score 16):

If you are getting a `CondaIOError` with `conda` command, it means that the *conda* directory does not have enough permissions to download and save new libraries.

Just execute these commands in terminal, and you'll be good to go:

`sudo chown -R username /home/username/path-to-conda-folder/`

`sudo chmod -R +x /home/username/path-to-conda-folder/`

Change **username** and **path-to-conda-folder** according to your PC.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: FYI - this didn't worked

Comment: FYI - this did work. Conda installed in /opt/anaconda3.

Answer (score 11):

You can do the following
Before running the sudo command type

```
which conda
```

then use the full conda path

```
sudo ~/install/ananconda//5.1../etc install myPackageName
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As you can see, this question was asked YEARS ago and already has an accepted answer. Please don't add answers to ancient question which don't give any improvement to the accepted answer.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this existing answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/588497/sudo-conda-command-not-found/1065144#1065144

Comment: Thank you so much. its works for me.

Comment: worked for me . thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to run with sudo permissions you shoud run conda specifying explicity the path of the conda executable. That path can ve investigated with which conda.